# What to do when two highly upvoted answers contradict each other?

Tags: discussion, answers

So here is a situation:

There is a problem I am interested in and I found exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5529625/1090562) on SO. But two of the answers (both pretty upvoted) contradict each other. How is it possible to resolve the problem?

To make things worse, I am really new to the library I am planning to use, so I can not quickly judge which one of the answers is the correct one.

I am sure this is not the only question with such a problem and it can be very confusing for the newcomer to see two contradicting answers.

Comment: Where's the contradiction between "there's no solution in the library" and "here's an implementation: <tons of code>"? The answers *agree* with each other.

Comment: @Veedrac now after you pointed it, it kind of makes sense that there is no contradiction, but when I read it in the first place it looked pretty contradictionary to me. First of all note that the OP does not ask for 1 line function that should be included in the library, he just asks how to do this, and the answerer shortens the scope and tells no. If I will ask how to reload a page with jquery, the answer, "no you can not do this with jquery" is not helpful, but use location.reload is. So the answer a broad question with an answer that limits the scope and tells 'No' is at least misleading.

Comment: @SalvadorDali "he just asks how to do this" - actually no he doesn't, he only asks *if it is possible*. Based on the question asked I find the epic WallOfCode answer quite over the top, I can only imagine the OP reads that and then ponders "errr, so... yes?" :)

Comment: @Gimby hence the problem with "is this possible" type questions.  An answer should assume that these questions always have an implicit, "if so, how?" part to the question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 don't agree, then the answers may be correct but the question will probably forever be the X/Y type.

Comment: @Gimby and an answer that is simply "Yes" or "No" is virtually worthless.  If I have a problem and I am looking to know if something is possible, I am looking to know **how** to accomplish what I want.

Comment: They're not both "pretty upvoted" - one has almost three times the votes than the other. That's a good indication that 3 times more people found it useful than the next answer.